# List all cookies with Laravel dusk

Tags: laravel, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk

Is there a method for laravel dusk to list all available cookies, instead of having to pass the cookie name to the `cookie($name)` method?

Comment: You can always run a script like e.g. `$cookiestring = $browser->driver->executeScript('return document.cookie')`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean current session cookie, you can use PHP's global `$_COOKIE`

If you want all cookies of all active sessions, I'm not sure there is such method in Laravel (it would overload the server too much, depending on your session driver). But surely you can create one. You should extend the base class `\Illuminate\Session\Store`

Comment: I guess that if I do $_COOKIE, it will show the cookie on the app side, which is not in the same process as Dusk test. (Like the code coverage does not work with Dusk tests).